# Java transform child class to parent one

Tags: java

Consider this code:

```
public class PublicInformation
{
    public String username;
    public String status;
}

public class PrivateInformation extends PublicInformation
{
    public String somePrivateInformation;
}
```

I have a `PrivateInformation` object, and I want to send it to store it on a stream, without the values of `PrivateInformation`. So I want to convert it to a `PublicInformation` object.

How should I do this? Is casting it to a `PublicInformation` object and send it through a stream enough?

Comment: No, because everybody else could cast your object back if they had access to your classes. But if you use a library to "send it to store it on a stream", it depends on how the library is implemented - for example, if the library knows your parent class and only requests values from the parent class contents it would send no more then requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that transforms you `PrivateInformation` into a `PublicInformation`, then send it :

```
public class PublicInformation
{
    public String username;
    public String status;
}

public class PrivateInformation extends PublicInformation
{
    public String somePrivateInformation;

    public PublicInformation prepareToSend(){
        return new PublicInformation(){username = this.username, status = this.status};
    }
}
```

Then you can call `PrivateInformation.prepareToSend()` to store it

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid that at first so I don't have to modify the function when I add/remove `PrivateInformation' members. But I guess this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending where your stream is. If it is a stream controlled by you, simply pass on the object. If it is a stream out of your control you must remove all the unnecessary data.

I see two solutions:

```
PrivateInformation privateInfo = new PrivateInformation();
...
privateInfo.setSomePrivateInformation(null);
...
```

or you write your own converter

```
public interface Converter<T, S>{
    public <S> convert(T src, S target)
}


public MyConverter implements Converter<PrivateInfo, PublicInfo> {
    public <S> convert(T src, S target) {
        PublicInfo tmp = new PublicInfo();
        tmp.setA(target.getA());
        tmp.setB(target.getB());

        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a cunstructor for `PublicInformation` that takes an instance of `PublicInformation` as a parameter.

```
public PublicInformation(PublicInformation other) {
  this.username = other.getUsername();
  this.status = other.getStatus();
}
```

Then call this constructor with an instance of `PrivateInformation`:

```
PrivateInformation privateInformation = new PrivateInformation();
// set username, status, and somePrivateInformation

PublicInformation publicInformation = new PublicInformation(privateInformation);
```

The resulting `publicInfromation` will be what you want.